# Can unused class members make code corrupt itself?

Tags: c++, class, oop, member

My code displays erratic behavior. I suspect a certain class member of being the cause of the issue. What startles me is that if a declare another member in the same class, my code starts working fine. This is the only change I apply to the code: declaring another class member. I'm not assigning any value to it, nothing. Just declaring it. Also, if I delete an unused class member, the issue is solved. What is the effect of having unused class members?

```
class Heroes() 
{ 
public: 
//All the class members

int TRG; //The one I suspect being the issue 

int FakeClassMember; //If I add this one, problem disappears 
};
```

Comment: Can you illustrate the issue with some code?

Comment: You're probably corrupting memory somewhere. Adding unused members changes the size of objects of the class, which can move things around and mean that your corruption has less obvious effects.

Comment: Are you using Visual C++?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Visual C++.

Here's some code:

class Heroes()
{
public:
//All the class members

int TRG; //The one I suspect being the issue

int FakeClassMember; //If I add this one, problem disappears
};

Comment: An `int` class member isn't the cause of your issue. How and/or what you're doing when modifying your `Heroes` objects *is*. There is nowhere *near* enough information provided in this post to garner even a reasonably speculative answer, much-less a conclusive one. I've no doubt you're corrupting memory by invoking undefined behavior, but without *real* code and likely an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) the best you're going to get is wags.

Answer (score 1):

So - One thing as Alan suggested is that you may corrupt your memory. For example in one place you use sizeof(your class) and in other place you type in a value that you may think is correct.

Another thing is that you use Visual C++ and things may be completely opposite than you think. Once you add your 'unused' member you may actually corrupt some code with it if it has invalid name, was declared already, etc. In such case if your Visual C++ is configured to run last correct program (see below). In such a case you run program that had no 'unused' member but you think that adding it fixes things. Check the setting below and read compiler warnings. It is little tangled but happens a lot to unwary. Do not just clisk run/ok etc.

[image]